# Excel 2010 Pivot Table issue

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have the below pivot table

```
Category    Total Count(calculated value)      # Completed Count(calculated value) 
  Red        38,357                                 18822
  Blue       182                                     155
  Green      7,153                                  4,761
```

I would not like to calculate a % of the two counts. So show the % of 18,822/38,357, etc. How would I go about getting this metric?

Comment: I'm using calculated fields. I added the calculation 38657-18822 and I get 19,512 but that value is copied down for every field.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a calculated Field. In the formula box divide by the true column name. So for instance if it's a calcululated value Count of "xx" exlcude the count of and use only the column name.